# How to configure transaction-type="JTA" programmatically (without persistence.xml")?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jta

Can I set `transaction-type "JTA"` when creating `EntityManagerFactory` in configuration java class without any .xml configs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to override the `javax.persistence.transactionType` property in this way:

```java
Map configOverrides = new HashMap();
configOverrides.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "JTA");
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("yourPersistenceUnitName", configOverrides);
```

But it looks like the `PersistenceException` exception will be raised if the `META-INF/persistence.xml` file is absent in your classpath.

See the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.4/reference/en/html/configuration.html) (section **2.2.2. Bootstrapping**).